# NullPointerException related to File

Tags: java, swing, file, nullpointerexception

Working from [this example](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/containers/20dialogs/30filechooser.html), I'm trying to break up the logic from the swing elements initialization and actions, while trying retrieve some information from the fileChooser, for other purposes.

When I run it, I get a `NullPointerException` after I open a file, attempt to open it, and setting fileCT to a value.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FileOpenTest extends JFrame {

    //====================================================== fields
    JTextField _fileNameTF = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField _wordCountTF = new JTextField(4);
    JFileChooser _fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    File file = _fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    //================================================= constructor
    FileOpenTest() {
        //... Create / set component characteristics.
        _fileNameTF.setEditable(false);
        _wordCountTF.setEditable(false);

        //... Add listeners

        //... Create content pane, layout components
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(new JLabel("File:"));
        content.add(_fileNameTF);
        content.add(new JLabel("Word Count:"));
        content.add(_wordCountTF);

        //... Create menu elements (menubar, menu, menu item)
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        openItem.addActionListener(new OpenAction());

        //... Assemble the menu
        menubar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(openItem);

        //... Set window characteristics
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        this.setContentPane(content);
        this.setTitle("Count Words");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();                      // Layout components.
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center window.
    }

    //============================================= countWordsInFile
    private int countWordsInFile(File file) {

        int numberOfWords = 0;  // Count of words.

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String word = in.next();  // Read a "token".
                numberOfWords++;
            }
            in.close();        // Close Scanner's file.

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            // ... We just got the file from the JFileChooser,
            //     so it's hard to believe there's problem, but...
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FileOpenTest.this,
                    fnfex.getMessage());
        }
        return numberOfWords;
    }

    public int getCountWordsInFile(File file) {
        return this.countWordsInFile(file);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// OpenAction

    class OpenAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //... Open a file dialog.
            int retval = _fileChooser.showOpenDialog(FileOpenTest.this);
            if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                //... The user selected a file, get it, use it.

                //... Update user interface.
                _fileNameTF.setText(file.getName());
                _wordCountTF.setText("" + countWordsInFile(file));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the class I'm initializing the window from:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FYI {
    static int getCount; 
    static FileOpenTest fOT = new FileOpenTest(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new FileOpenTest();
        window.setVisible(true);

        File fileCT = fOT.file;

        while (fileCT != null){
                getCount = fOT.getCountWordsInFile(fileCT);
                System.out.print(getCount + "<-- got count!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot if you tell us _where_ (in which line of the code) the null pointer exception occurs.

Comment: the null pointer exception occurred at                 _fileNameTF.setText(file.getName());

Answer (score 2):

You read the field `file` within your actionlistener and your main method. This field is only written once, namely in the initialization of class `FileOpenTest`:

```
File file = _fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

This is called straight after the `JFileChooser` is instanciated and at this point no file is selected yet.

The file chooser will change its selected file when called. Thus, after the file dialog is closed you need to re-get the file object:

```
//... The user selected a file, get it, use it.
file = _fileChooser.getSelectedFile();  // <= insert something like this here.
```

Comment: This did take care of the null pointer exception, but I'm still not able to get any output from: while (fileCT != null){
                getCount = fOT.getCountWordsInFile(fileCT);
                System.out.print(getCount + "<-- got count!");
        } in my main method.

Comment: @DOLOisSOLO Here the issue is that `window.setVisible(true)` does not wait until your window is closed or any action takes place. Instead the main method runs along and at this point in time you didn't yet select any file. Thus `fOT.file` is null. Therefore it doesn't make sense to place this code within `main()`. Please read the [introduction to swing programming](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).